# Where to plug in the factory method in the abstract factory pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

// Abstract factory class

```
class pizzaStore
{
     public:
      vector <string> toppingsType;

      virtual void bakePizza        (){}
      virtual void preparePizza     ()
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < toppingsType.size (); i++)
           {
            addTopping (toppingsType[i]);
           }
      }

      virtual void cutPizza         (){}
      virtual void boxPizza     (){}
};

class xPizzaStore : public pizzaStore
{
     xPizzaStore () 
     {
      toppingsType = "1";
      sauceType      = "2";
      cheesetype     = "3";
     }

     void orderPizza ()
     {
      bakePizza ();
      preparePizza ();
      // xPizzaStore doesn't cut the pizza.
      boxPizza ();
     }
};
```

// Factory method for creating stores

```
pizzaStore * whichStore (string storeName)
{
      pizzaStore obj = NULL;

      if (storeName == "x")
      {
           obj = new xPizzaStore ();
      }
      else if (storeName == "y")
      {
           obj = new yPizzaStore ();
      }
      else if (storeName == "z")
      {
           obj = new zPizzaStore ();
      }

      return obj;
}
```

// Factory method for creating pizzas

```
pizzaStore * whichPizza (string pizzaName)
{
      pizzaName obj = NULL;

      if (pizzaBaseType == "x")
      {
           obj = new xPizzaName ();
      }
      else if (pizzaBaseType == "y")
      {
           obj = new yPizzaName ();
      }
      else if (pizzaBaseType == "z")
      {
           obj = new zPizzaName ();
      }

      return obj;
}
```

There can be different types of stores as well as pizzas.
In which class should these two factory methods be included and why?
Does it make sense to include them in the pizzaStore class itself?

Comment: Anisha, why would you need to plug the factory methods into a class? To me it seems perfectly fine to leave them as free functions.

Comment: Why does `whichPizza` method return `pizzaStore*`? I guess it is a typo, and you haven't shown base class (e.g. `PizzaName`, or just `Pizza`) for different pizza classes (`xPizaName`, `yPizzaName`, `zPizzaName`). I would put `whichPizza` as a virtual method in base class `pizzaStore` but still...can `xPizzaStore` create `yPizzaName` and `zPizzaName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it make sense to include them in the pizzaStore class itself?

**Yes**, it should be perfectly fine to put those method in `class pizzaStore` as `static` methods. Generally I consider, putting such factory method in a `class` based on its `return` type, and `pizzaStore` is a good candidate for it.